# "Error: java.sql.SQLException" When exporting database table to excel AnyLogic

Tags: anylogic

I am trying to export a table from AnyLogic's database to an excel file in a parameters variation using this code:

```
Database myFile = new Database(this, "A DB from Excel", "DataBaseExport.xlsx");
ModelDatabase modelDB = getEngine().getModelDatabase();
modelDB.exportToExternalDB("flowchart_stats_time_in_state_log", myFile.getConnection(), "Sheet 1", true, true);
```

I am then given this error
[image]

With this after

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the name of the excel sheet "sheet1" is the culprit. Upon removing the "1" and creating matching column names in the excel file, the data is able to be exported.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about your issue, but maybe try this instead:

1. create a database object as below:
   [image]
2. Call this code at runtime:
   [image]

Comment: Unfortunately PLE does not allow Database. But, the problem has been solved.